# Messages when attempting to empty Trash in macOS

Tags: macos

I getting these message when attempting to empty my trash in Mac:

```
Cinna-MacMini:.Trashes stevechang$ rm -rf 502/sda/
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users/stevechang/Library/Application Support/Manroling/Manroling.app: Operation not permitted
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users/stevechang/Library/Application Support/Manroling: Operation not permitted
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users/stevechang/Library/Application Support: Permission denied
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users/stevechang/Library: Permission denied
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users/stevechang: Permission denied
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini/Users: Permission denied
rm: 502/sda//Cinna Macmini: Permission denied
rm: 502/sda/: Permission denied
```

What does the messages mean?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It would help if you can edit the question and provide details such as the version of macOS running on your Mac. It would also help if you can mention if the username of your account matches with the one mentioned in the file path, i.e. `stevechang `.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the messages are pretty straight forward I suppose, you do not have the correct permission to remove these files.

I am however a bit confused as to the term "empty Trash". It seems that this can be accomplished using the GUI and this would be the preferred way to do it? The files you are trying to completely wipe of your system does not seem to be in the "trash"?

Anyway, running the same command as 'sudo' should solve your problem although I would be careful as it seems from your output that you are attempting to erase more than trashed files:

502/sda/: Permission denied

Unless you intentionally put an entire partition in the trash? The 'rm' command is not recoverable.